# to know which link is clicked in the previous page using jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, jstl

jsp code to know which link is clicked in previous page,
based on that to change the web page content of second page.
Help me to write code for this.

Comment: Just attach the last-clicked link to the querystring. `<a href="biography?lastclicked=contact"></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have one JSP for all links, do something like this:

**main.jsp:**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="detail.jsp?link=page1">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="detail.jsp?link=page2">Page 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**detail.jsp:**

```
<h1>I am on Detail Page</h1>
<% String link = request.getParameter("link"); %>
```

Then use this variable as per your need.